# Error when trying to compile abgx360: C++ compiler cannot create executables

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile the abgx360 GUI.

First I run `home/eric/Desktop/abgx360-1.0.5/configure` but I receive this error:

> checking for C++ compiler default output file name...
>
> configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
>
> See `config.log' for more details.

Then i run `make` but I receive this error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360-1.0.5/Makefile.am',
>
> needed by `/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360-1.0.5/Makefile.in'.  Stop.

Here is my 'config.log':

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by abgx360gui configure 1.0.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Eric-Desktop
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.35-27-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 22 20:25:46 UTC 2011

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1800: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1856: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:1867: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1910: result: yes
configure:1938: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:1977: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:1990: checking for gawk
configure:2020: result: no
configure:1990: checking for mawk
configure:2006: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2017: result: mawk
configure:2028: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2049: result: yes
configure:2302: checking for g++
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for c++
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for gpp
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for aCC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for CC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for cxx
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for cc++
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for cl.exe
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for FCC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for KCC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for RCC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for xlC_r
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2302: checking for xlC
configure:2332: result: no
configure:2360: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:2367: g++ --version >&5
/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure: line 2368: g++: command not found
configure:2370: $? = 127
configure:2377: g++ -v >&5
/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure: line 2378: g++: command not found
configure:2380: $? = 127
configure:2387: g++ -V >&5
/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure: line 2388: g++: command not found
configure:2390: $? = 127
configure:2413: checking for C++ compiler default output file name
configure:2440: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure: line 2441: g++: command not found
configure:2443: $? = 127
configure:2481: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "abgx360gui"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "abgx360gui"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "abgx360gui 1.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE "abgx360gui"
| #define VERSION "1.0.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2488: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run aclocal-1.10'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run tar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run automake-1.10'
AWK='mawk'
CC=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/missing --run makeinfo'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='abgx360gui'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='abgx360gui'
PACKAGE_STRING='abgx360gui 1.0.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='abgx360gui'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='1.0.2'
WX_CFLAGS=''
WX_CFLAGS_ONLY=''
WX_CONFIG_PATH=''
WX_CPPFLAGS=''
WX_CXXFLAGS=''
WX_CXXFLAGS_ONLY=''
WX_LIBS=''
WX_LIBS_STATIC=''
WX_RESCOMP=''
WX_VERSION=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=' -I$(srcdir)'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='$(SHELL) /home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "abgx360gui"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "abgx360gui"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "abgx360gui 1.0.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE "abgx360gui"
#define VERSION "1.0.2"

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is very obvious:

```
/home/eric/Desktop/abgx360gui-1.0.2/configure: line 2441: g++: command not found
```

Solution: install the C++ compiler, `g++`:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables can be solved by installing  “g++” on your ubuntu machine.

checkout at

http://www.prowebguru.com/2011/11/ubuntu-configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables/

Comment: This seems like advertising, post the contents of the link here

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.